# Same Code giving different results in Visual Studio 2010 and Code Blocks 10.05

Tags: c++

I am executing a filter code .This Code gives different results in Visual Studio and Code Blocks.Expected Results are the results which code blocks gives.But As i have to implement Intel Thread Building Blocks into it i have to use Visual Studio.Please help in finding why the difference is there.

```
Code is :


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include  <time.h>
using namespace std;

#define pi 3.141593
#define FILTER_LEN  265

double coeffs[ FILTER_LEN ] =
{
  0.0033473431384214393,0.000032074683390218124,0.0033131082058404943,0.0024777666109278788,
  -0.0008968429179843104,-0.0031973449396977684,-0.003430943381749411,-0.0029796565504781646,
  -0.002770673157048994,-0.0022783059845596586,-0.0008531818129514857,0.001115432556294998,
  0.0026079871108133294,0.003012423848769931,0.002461420635709332,0.0014154004589753215,
  0.00025190669718400967,-0.0007608257014963959,-0.0013703600874774068,-0.0014133823230551277,
  -0.0009759556503342884,-0.00039687498737139273,-0.00007527524701314324,-0.00024181463305012626,
  -0.0008521761947454302,-0.00162618205097997,-0.002170446498273018,-0.002129903305507943,
  -0.001333859049002249,0.00010700092934983156,0.0018039564602637683,0.0032107930896349583,
  0.0038325849735515363,0.003416201274366522,0.002060848732332109,0.00017954815260431595,
  -0.0016358832300944531,-0.0028402136847527387,-0.0031256650498727384,-0.0025374271571154713,
  -0.001438370315670195,-0.00035115295209013755,0.0002606730012030533,0.0001969569787142967,
  -0.00039635535951198597,-0.0010886127490608972,-0.0013530057243606405,-0.0008123200399262436,
  0.0005730271959526784,0.0024419465938120906,0.004133717273258681,0.0049402122577746265,
  0.0043879285604252714,0.002449549610687005,-0.00040283102645093463,-0.003337730734820209,
  -0.0054508346511294775,-0.006093057767824609,-0.005117609782189977,-0.0029293645861970417,
  -0.0003251033117661085,0.0018074390555649442,0.0028351284091668164,0.002623563404428517,
  0.0015692864792199496,0.0004127664681096788,-0.00009249878881824428,0.0004690173244168184,
  0.001964334172374759,0.0037256715492873485,0.004809640399145206,0.004395274594482053,
  0.0021650921193604,-0.0014888595443799124,-0.005534807968511709,-0.008642334104607624,
  -0.009668950651149259,-0.008104732391434574,-0.004299972815463919,0.0006184612821881392,
  0.005136551428636121,0.007907786753766152,0.008241212326068366,0.00634786595941524,
  0.003235610213062744,0.00028882736660937287,-0.001320994685952108,-0.0011237433853145615,
  0.00044213409507615003,0.0022057106517524255,0.00277593527678719,0.0011909915058737617,
  -0.0025807757230413447,-0.007497632882437637,-0.011739520895818884,-0.013377018279057393,
  -0.011166543231844196,-0.005133056165990026,0.0032948631959114935,0.011673660427968408,
  0.017376415708412904,0.018548938130314566,0.014811760899506572,0.007450782505155853,
  -0.001019540069785369,-0.007805775815783898,-0.010898333714715424,-0.00985364043415772,
  -0.005988406030111452,-0.001818560524968024,0.000028552677472614846,-0.0019938756495376363,
  -0.007477684025727061,-0.013989430449615033,-0.017870518868849213,-0.015639422062597726,
  -0.005624959109456065,0.010993528170353541,0.03001263681283932,0.04527492462846608,
  0.050581340787164114,0.041949186532860346,0.019360612460662185,-0.012644336735920483,
  -0.0458782599058412,-0.07073838953156347,-0.0791205623455818,-0.06709535677423759,
  -0.03644544574795176,0.005505370370858695,0.04780486657828151,0.07898800597378192,
  0.0904453420042807,0.07898800597378192,0.04780486657828151,0.005505370370858695,
  -0.03644544574795176,-0.06709535677423759,-0.0791205623455818,-0.07073838953156347,
  -0.0458782599058412,-0.012644336735920483,0.019360612460662185,0.041949186532860346,
  0.050581340787164114,0.04527492462846608,0.03001263681283932,0.010993528170353541,
  -0.005624959109456065,-0.015639422062597726,-0.017870518868849213,-0.013989430449615033,
  -0.007477684025727061,-0.0019938756495376363,0.000028552677472614846,-0.001818560524968024,
  -0.005988406030111452,-0.00985364043415772,-0.010898333714715424,-0.007805775815783898,
  -0.001019540069785369,0.007450782505155853,0.014811760899506572,0.018548938130314566,
  0.017376415708412904,0.011673660427968408,0.0032948631959114935,-0.005133056165990026,
  -0.011166543231844196,-0.013377018279057393,-0.011739520895818884,-0.007497632882437637,
  -0.0025807757230413447,0.0011909915058737617,0.00277593527678719,0.0022057106517524255,
  0.00044213409507615003,-0.0011237433853145615,-0.001320994685952108,0.00028882736660937287,
  0.003235610213062744,0.00634786595941524,0.008241212326068366,0.007907786753766152,
  0.005136551428636121,0.0006184612821881392,-0.004299972815463919,-0.008104732391434574,
  -0.009668950651149259,-0.008642334104607624,-0.005534807968511709,-0.0014888595443799124,
  0.0021650921193604,0.004395274594482053,0.004809640399145206,0.0037256715492873485,
  0.001964334172374759,0.0004690173244168184,-0.00009249878881824428,0.0004127664681096788,
  0.0015692864792199496,0.002623563404428517,0.0028351284091668164,0.0018074390555649442,
  -0.0003251033117661085,-0.0029293645861970417,-0.005117609782189977,-0.006093057767824609,
  -0.0054508346511294775,-0.003337730734820209,-0.00040283102645093463,0.002449549610687005,
  0.0043879285604252714,0.0049402122577746265,0.004133717273258681,0.0024419465938120906,
  0.0005730271959526784,-0.0008123200399262436,-0.0013530057243606405,-0.0010886127490608972,
  -0.00039635535951198597,0.0001969569787142967,0.0002606730012030533,-0.00035115295209013755,
  -0.001438370315670195,-0.0025374271571154713,-0.0031256650498727384,-0.0028402136847527387,
  -0.0016358832300944531,0.00017954815260431595,0.002060848732332109,0.003416201274366522,
  0.0038325849735515363,0.0032107930896349583,0.0018039564602637683,0.00010700092934983156,
  -0.001333859049002249,-0.002129903305507943,-0.002170446498273018,-0.00162618205097997,
  -0.0008521761947454302,-0.00024181463305012626,-0.00007527524701314324,-0.00039687498737139273,
  -0.0009759556503342884,-0.0014133823230551277,-0.0013703600874774068,-0.0007608257014963959,
  0.00025190669718400967,0.0014154004589753215,0.002461420635709332,0.003012423848769931,
  0.0026079871108133294,0.001115432556294998,-0.0008531818129514857,-0.0022783059845596586,
  -0.002770673157048994,-0.0029796565504781646,-0.003430943381749411,-0.0031973449396977684,
  -0.0008968429179843104,0.0024777666109278788,0.0033131082058404943,0.000032074683390218124,
  0.0033473431384214393
};

void ComputeFIR(double *coeffs, double *input,  int filterLength,ofstream &o )
{
    double acc;
    double *coeffp;
    int n,k,ip,nip;
    o<<fixed;
    for ( n = 0; n < 150000; n++ )
    {
        coeffp = coeffs;
        ip=(filterLength - 1 + n);
        nip=0;

        acc = 0;
        for ( k = 0; k < filterLength; k++ )
        {
            nip=ip-k;
            acc += ((*coeffp++) * (input[nip]));                  //      *inputp--  we can't use bcoz dynamic memory is not neccasarily in sequence);
        }
        o<<n<<","<<acc<<endl;
        if(n<10)
        {
            cout<<n<<"\t"<<acc<<endl;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int i;

    ofstream o("400hz.csv");
    cout<<fixed;
    o<<fixed;
    double *buffer=new double[150264];                             //      Length required to process M input samples is N-1+M  where N is MAC , M is the Number of samples

   memset(buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer));

   for(i =(FILTER_LEN - 1); i < 150264; i++)
   {
            buffer[i] = sin(400 * (2 * pi) * (i / 5000.0));
            o<<i<<","<<buffer[i]<<endl;
    }

   ComputeFIR( coeffs,buffer,FILTER_LEN,o );

   delete []buffer;
   return 0;
}
```

In this code part

```
if(n<10)
            {
                cout<<n<<"\t"<<acc<<endl;
            }
```

gives results in code blocks as

> 0 0.002291
>
> 1 0.003205
>
> 2 0.005587
>
> 3 0.007458
>
> 4 0.006254
>
> 5 0.001537
>
> 6 -0.005113
>
> 7 -0.011685
>
> 8 -0.0016522
>
> 9 -0.018142

which are as expected

and in Visual Studio results are

> 0 7.86052E+64
>
> 1 7.88065E+64
>
> 2 9.96043E+64
>
> 3 1.15158E+65
>
> 4 1.09528E+65
>
> 5 8.94574E+64
>
> 6 6.79198E+64
>
> 7 4.92152E+64
>
> 8 3.18225E+64
>
> 9 1.75206E+64

Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line doesn't initialise your buffer to zero:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer));
```

You need

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(double) * 150264);
```

Maybe CodeBlocks and VS2012 differ in the way that they are initialising that buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same code do different result when using different compilers is a sure sign of undefined behavior.

The reason behind this undefined behavior is because of this:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer));
```

The first problem is that the variable `buffer` is a pointer, and so using `sizeof(buffer)` you get the size of the actual pointer and not what it points to. This means that only four or eight bytes (depending on if you have a 32 or 64 bit platform) will be initialized to zero. The rest of the memory will be seemingly random.

The second problem, which works in this case (but only in this case), is that you are setting all data to zero. Floating point numbers are not stored like normal integer numbers in memory. You can't use `memset` with any other value and expect the numbers to be what you want.

Comment: "You can't use..." In general, yes. But with IEEE floating-point (i.e., almost all real-world implementations) setting the bits to 0 does create a value of 0.0.